# Finding equally spaced points given a set of points with line segments in between

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm currently programming a map, and am trying to split street segments into equal parts. If a street segment is straight it's a simple matter of dividing the length of the street segment by whatever factor you want. However, curvy streets are much harder to divide into equal parts, as they are made up of multiple segments. What I want to do is figure out a way to divide a street segment into equal points, regardless of how curvy it is, or how long each segment is. I tried parameterising the curve to get this to work, but it still doesn't work. To see what I mean by parameterizing, check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4055884/parameterise-a-line-represented-by-n-points/4055908?noredirect=1#comment8378371_4055908) out.

At the moment, this is how I am currently implementing it.

```
        //street_seg_length is length of the ith street segment
        for (double j = 0.0; j < street_seg_length[i]; j+=inc) { 
        
        double rem = j - int(j);
        //A street segment can be split up into multiple curve points. 
        //The more curve points, the curvier a road is
        LatLon from = curve_points_pos[i][int(j)];
        LatLon to = curve_points_pos[i][int(j)+1];
        //Returns cartesian coordinates from latitude and longitude of nth and n+1th curve point
        double x1 = x_from_lon(from.longitude());
        double y1 = y_from_lat(from.latitude());
        double x2 = x_from_lon(to.longitude());
        double y2 = y_from_lat(to.latitude());
        //arrowX, arrowY are supposed to be the coordinates of a point between 2 curve points
        double arrowX = (1 - rem)*x1 + rem*x2;
        double arrowY = (1 - rem) * y1 + rem * y2;
        
         
         
        }
        
    }
```

rem is the remainder discussed in the above post, j is the same value as t in the above post, p is the nth point and q is the n+1th point discussed in the above post.

Can someone explain what I can do to achieve this or what I'm doing wrong? I want to find equally spaced points across a street segment regardless of how curvy it is. Am I following the algorithm in the linked post correctly? I believe I am but clearly the algorithm is wrong or I haven't implemented it correctly, the latter being more probable.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @MOehm Sorry, guess it was a bit vague. I updated the end of the post with my question.

Comment: `double arrowX = (1 - rem)*x1 + rem*x2;` Here you want `rem` to be a number between `0` and `1`, where `rem = 0` means `arrowX = x1` and `rem = 1` means `arrowX = x2`. Maybe something like `rem = j / street_seg_length[i];` though there is not enough context to be sure, but almost certainly not `rem = j - int(j);`.

Comment: Yes, it is not clear what `inc` is. Your code needs to do two things: Find out which segment the current "arrow"  is in and then find out at which position in the segment the arrow is. It looks as if you were mixing up what `j` is, a segment index or a running length. You want it to be a bit of both, but that can't be.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for the suggestion, but why would it not be j - int(j)? if j is 2.6, rem would be 0.6, which is what I'm looking for. Also, how could I provide more context?

Comment: @MOehm inc is the length I want to increment each time. Say I had a street of length 5 and inc = 0.25, I would place an arrow every 0.25 meters, which would happen 20 times in a street of length 5. As for j, I simply followed the instructions in the post I linked. Have I misunderstood the post? The post says to take the integer value of the t (in this code, j) and extract point[j] and point[j+1] then use the remainder in the formula, which I expressed as rem = j - int(j).

Comment: But then your code works only if your street is 5m long and each segment is 1m long. But I don't think that's the case: You have long straight segments and you have small segments where the curvature is high. So j is your "running length" over the whole segment. Now you must find out (1) the segment index and (b) the interpolation parameter t in that segment for each j.

Comment: @OmarFarag You don't say what `i` and `inc` are, and you don't show the outer loop which presumably encloses the `j` loop. I don't see the reason why `0.6` would be what `rem` is supposed to be. For one thing, `j - int(j)` will not be monotonic in general, so those points may be jumping back and forth.

Comment: @MOehm Ah, I see your point. I will try to fix that. Thanks

Comment: @dxiv You are correct, it will not be monotonic. What I'm trying to do is overshoot one point, then undershoot the next, and so on. However I do see your point, and will try to change my implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resulting path `+` will have equidistant points, but your original path `o` has segments of different length. You have two different things to deal with:

- the indices `curr` and `next` of the start and end points of the current segment and
- the interpolation variable `t` for that segment.

Here's an example of `curr / next` values:

```
o    +        0 / 1       t = 0.0
|    |
|    +        0 / 1       t = 0.667
o    |
|    +        1 / 2       t = 0.2
|    |
|    +        1 / 2       t = 0.6
|    |
o    +        1 / 2       t = 1.0
```

So your algorithm goes like this:

- find the overall and accumulated segment lengths;
- start with `curr = 0` and `next = 1`.
- loop over the n equidistant points:

  - determine the overall running length `z` of that point
  - adjust `curr` and `next`, so that `curr ≤ z ≤ next`.
  - determine `t` and interpolate

Here's an implementation that splits a path `seg` into `n` segments of the same length. (It's not in C++, but in Javascript and it deals with (x, y)  coordinates directly instead of lon/lat, but I hink you can understand it.)

```
function split(seg, n) {
    let acc = [];               // n + 1 accumulated lengths
    let len = 0;                // overall length
    let p = seg[0];              
    
    let res = [];               // array of n + 1 result points
    
    // find segemnt and overall lengths
    
    for (let i = 0; i < seg.length; i++) {
        let q = seg[i];
        len += Math.hypot(q.x - p.x, q.y - p.y);
        acc.push(len);

        p = q;
    }
    
    acc.push(2 * len);          // sentinel

    let curr = 0;
    let next = 1;
    
    // create equidistant result points
    
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let z = len * i / n;        // running length of point i
        
        // advance to current segment
        
        while (z > acc[next]) {
            curr++;
            next++;
        }
        
        // interpolate in segment
                
        let p = seg[curr];
        let q = seg[next];
        
        let t = (z - acc[curr]) / (acc[next] - acc[curr]);
        
        res.push(new Point(p.x * (1 - t) + q.x * t,
                           p.y * (1 - t) + q.y * t));
    }
    
    // push end point (leave out when joining consecutive segments.)
    
    res.push(seg[seg.length - 1]);
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I've been stuck with for the past few days. I got it to work after a bit of tinkering with your code. Really appreciate it :)